# objc_exception_throw exception with AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings Method

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I got an exception in Apple approval process and not sure why. I could not repeat it in my local iPad.

Now, in my xcode IDE 9.3, for the swift file, photoOutput is the only one shows up. When tested by Apple for approval, they kept showing me the following error:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

and the call trace is:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1834d2d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18268c5ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   AVFoundation                    0x18905adc4 -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] + 811
3   MyApp                       0x10082fa1c closure #1 in SnapViewController.snapAction(_:) + 64028 (SnapViewController.swift:0)
4   MyApp                       0x10083f6ac _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR + 128684 (BasicPopoverTableViewController.swift:0)
```

Here is my codes -

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {                      
  let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg,
           AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [AVVideoQualityKey : NSNumber(value: COMPRESSION_QUALITY)]])
  photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
  photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
  photoSettings.flashMode = .auto          
  self.capturePhotoOutput!.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
}



extension SnapViewController : AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {    
  func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
                 error: Error?) {
   ......
  }
}
```

I am not sure how objc_exception_throw jumps out and in my local testing of 11.3, I have never seen that. What I could do to figure out the reason?

Also, very interestingly, BasicPopoverTableViewController.swift should never be used at this stage. This is used for some Popover code that should never be associated with the `SnapViewController.snapAction(_:)`. I am a bit worried about the sybolicating process.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, my tentative conclusion is, it is a bug with ios 11.x. I got the same error when I tried to profile the app. After looking through everything there, it appears to be caused by a buggy implementation of UIImage(contentOf..). Change my release target from 11.0 to 11.3 seems solved my problem at least in the profiling step. My fingers crossed. ..

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the format you constructed the photo setttings with. You are capturing a still image but passing in video compression settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @Spads said, the error was caused by content of AVCapturePhotoSettings. I did not query device capacities before setting the option and that created messy none-informative errors. I make the following changes and Apple now accepted the app.

```
if (self.captureDevice!.isFlashAvailable){
            photoSettings.flashMode = .auto
        }
        else {
            photoSettings.flashMode = .off
        }

        if self.capturePhotoOutput!.isStillImageStabilizationSupported {
            photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
        }

        photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
```